# Why the aws console has some parts on english and other in spanish

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm learning about the AWS console and there some parts on english and others on spanish
look:
[image]

Any idea how can i change to only english? I already tried to change the language and it's on english so i don't know what to do, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how, you gotta change it to other language and then change it back to english, always saving after a change and it's done